# Increment variable in Batch for rendering

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing, batch-rename

I have this code. It loads a sequence of .vrscene files

```
for /f %%a IN ('dir /b /s "C:\Users\Beqarion\Desktop\test_for_batch*.vrscene"') do call "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2015\vray\bin\vray.exe" -scenefile=%%a -imgFile="C:\Users\Beqarion\Desktop\test_for_batch\img.jpg" -frames=1 -autoclose=1
```

As you can see at the end it has an img output and frame number. I need to create a variable that will increment every time a `.vrscene` file is rendered and add it to `img.jpg` so that it saves a new img file after every render: `img_0001`, `img_0002` etc. I tried `set /a varname+=1` but it doesn't work. Also I want to add that I'm not a programmer and I don't code in batch. So things that some of people here consider very basic may not be for me.

Comment: If it was easy you would be able to do it yourself.  Please provide more detail to your question.  Provide examples.

Comment: `set /a "varname=varname+1"`

Comment: better: `set /a varname+=1`

Comment: well i don't code in batch you see. so even if it is easy it's not so clear for me. here it is:  for /f %%a IN ('dir /b /s "C:\Users\Beqarion\Desktop\test_for_batch\*.vrscene"')  do call "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2015\vray\bin\vray.exe" -scenefile=%%a -imgFile="C:\Users\Beqarion\Desktop\test_for_batch\img.jpg"  -frames=1 -autoclose=1

Comment: so i need to add a variable to the "img.jpg" and "-frames" as well (instead of 1 i want -frames to be an incerement)

Comment: Please update your question using the edit facility, _(adding new information to your question will not help you to get positive responders)_.

Comment: how can i make it increment every time a frame is rendered? set /a varname+=1 doesn't do that :(

Comment: @beqarion, update your question with your code.  DO  NOT PUT IT IN  A COMMENT.

Answer (score 2):

```bat
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "Basefldr=C:\Users\Beqarion\Desktop"
Set "vray=C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2015\vray\bin\vray.exe"
Pushd "%Basefldr%"||(Echo can't cd to %Basefldr% &Pause &Exit /B 1)
Set ImgNo=10000
for /f "delims=" %%a IN (
  'dir /b /s "test_for_batch*.vrscene"'
) do (Set /A ImgNo+=1
  "%vray%" ^
  -scenefile=%%a ^
  -imgFile=".\test_for_batch\img_!ImgNo:~-4!.jpg" ^
  -frames=1 ^
  -autoclose=1
)
PopD
```

The initial `ImgNo=10000` is necessary to get the leading zeroes
when stripping the last four places with `!ImgNo:~-4!`
The use of EnableDelayedExpansion in combination with `!` instead 
of the usual `%` is required to get actual values in an area 
surrounded by parentheses.

Comment: New to StackExchange/stackoverflow doesn't mean new to batch ;-)

Comment: Obvioulsy... I hope you will stay here. You seem to have a lot to contribute. Welcome to the "club" `:)`

Comment: @LotPings, never been a big fan of that kind of syntax for batch files. I love my indentation and never wrap the IN clause like that, but in this instance it does make the code to execute the program easier to read. Welcome to StackOverFlow.

Comment: @Stephan et all. (can only have one at) Thanks for the welcome.